# Installing 3 way dimmer switch

Tags: electrical

Replacing 3 way switch with 3 way dimmer switch. The new dimmer switch is marked for 2 red and one black. The wiring is 2 black and one red. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The colours of wires usually don't mean much.  It is how the wires are placed on the switch.  Usually one black screw and two brass screws.  Wire on the black screw old goes to the black screw new.

Comment: There are no color codes in 3-ways.  It's all about function.

Comment: Take pictures of the **before** wiring, if it's not *already too late.* [Edit] your question to include them.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out and its working.